# Is ServiceInstaller getting obsolete in .NET 3.5+

Tags: c#, winforms

For using ServiceInstaller I had to go and add it manually to toolbox, it wasn't there by default. But there was something by default in toolbox called ServiceController.
So I was wondering if this is better and should be used instead of ServiceInstaller in new versions of .NET?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not obsolete (see [ServiceInstaller Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.serviceinstaller.aspx)). ServiceController is exactly what it sounds like a class for programmatically controlling the state of a Windows service (see [ServiceController Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller)). ServiceInstaller doesn't appear in the toolbox because it is usually added by using Add Installer to create the class in the service project (See [How to: Add Installers to Your Service Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ddhy0byf%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)).

Answer (score 1):

ServiceInstaller and ServiceController do completely different but related things

A `ServiceInstaller` is used for Windows Services. When a windows service gets installed on the machine ither through InstallUtil.exe or an Msi it gets run and allows you to do things like register an event source on the machine.

`ServiceController` is a class that allows you to connect to a service and do things like start and stop it via code. This can be used from any type of application.

No its not obsolete. It would be marked as deprecated if it were in the documentation. And it would likely have the ObsoleteAttribute attribute on its members. For example of that see [ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationsettings.appsettings)